# How can I get all column values from a panda dataframe and save them into one string

Tags: pandas, dataframe, excel

this question has been ask couple of times but none of the answer is working for that what I want.

For example I have this excel Dokument:

```
Numbers  Names  Address 
1        Ben    Street1
2        Anna   Street2
3        Tom    Street3
```

Now I want to store only the column **Names** into one string:

```
string_text = "Ben Anna Tom"
print(string_text)-> Ben Anna Tom
```

I tried this out:

```
string_text = str(df['Names'].values)
print (text)
```

and I get:

```
['Ben' 
'Anna' 
'Tom']
```

Is there any option I can get really only the value of each cell and concatenate them together without the apostrophes in between?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to create a list then you can use:

```
list(df['Names'].values[1:])
```

If you are looking to create a long string use join (you can of course choose any delimiter you like):

```
' '.join(df['Names'].values[1:])
```

Comment: if I do so, I will get a String where every char is separated and I still have the apostrophes.

Comment: and if I use to_string its truncates the strings of the cells

Comment: To get rid of the apostrophes use: print(' '.join(df['Names'].values))